# Converting column names into row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read the table from pdf using tabula

```
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf('xyz.pdf')
df.columns = ["Start_time","End_time","Start_stop_name","End_stop_name"]
```

Now if I'm assigning names to the column it overwrites on the 1st row.

[Before adding column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NPpl.jpg)

[After adding column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBgsT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing [`pandas_options`](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/tabula-py-0.9.0/autoapi/wrapper/index.html#wrapper.wrapper.read_pdf) parameter, with `{'header': None}`:

```
df = wrapper.read_pdf('xyz.pdf', pandas_options={‘header’: None})
```